# Passing extra arguments to a function in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am using a package "genalg" for Genetic Algorithm related functions. In this package there is a function called "rgba". When I call this function(rbga) I need to pass reference of another function(let A) (evaluation function written by user) as an argument and it (A) will be called by "rbga" function but I want to access some values in "A" that is not passed by "rbga" function to "A". I can use the environment variable for that purpose but is there any other way to do this?

> Edit:

```
evaluate<-function(x,y,z) # x,y,z arguments passed by rbga 
{ 
 q=p # p is neither x,y,z nor local to this function.
}

result<- rbga(..,evalFunc=evaluate,..) # calls the function evaluate.
```

In the function "evaluate" I want to use p. As p is not passed by the calling function and not local to the called function, I need to pass it somehow. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you got the functions reversed...

Comment: Read this three times and still have no idea what you are asking. Can you provide some sample code? Can you write out (preferably also in code) what your own attempts to resolve the problem were?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this problem, but like Paul Hiemstra says below, it seems to be impossible(try the package genoud, it allows for arguments to be passed). Unfortunately, the R community here in SO always down-votes the questions they don't know the answer to. But don't worry, there is nothing wrong or out of topic with your question.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation it appears that both types of user defined function have a clearly defined interface. `evalFunc` takes the vector of chromosomes, and `monitorFunc` an internal object which the package passes to this function which a user can get stuff from to for example plot.

In its current implementation it is not possible to add custom user defined arguments to these functions. Getting this to work would require some tweaks to the package code.